# Remove horizontal slice of an image and fill its void by the surrounding areas from above and below

Tags: image-processing, slice, batch-processing, crop, chop

### Original Images & Desired Outcome

I have a batch of PNG images which need the same automated image processing:

- Middle part (red) shall get eliminated entirely and its void filled from above/below
- Top (blue) and middle part (red) always have the same height
- The bottom part (green) may vary in height

[image: Original and Desired Outcome]

### How do I achieve this with a free script-able image processing suite?

- Such as ImageMagic or sips

Answer (score 1):

## ImageMagick -chop does just that

Man page on [-chop](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop):

> The -chop option removes entire rows and columns, and moves the remaining corner blocks leftward and upward to close the gaps.

Also handy is the counterpart function [-splice](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#splice):

> This will add rows and columns of the current -background color into the given image

### Chop out the undesired red row

[image]
→
[image]

`convert in.png -chop x92+0+50 out-chopped.png`

- `in.png` is the original image
- `out-chopped.png` is the desired outcome
- `-chop x92+0+50`: From the default reference point top left (could be changed with [-gravity](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity)) at x +0px and y +50px (after the top blue part we want to keep) chop out the red segment at full width (because no number is specified before the `x` and hence it assumes full canvas width) and at a height of 92px (had some seam, hence I added 2px to cut clean)

### Chop out the undesired red part + insert a thin separator row

[image]
→
[image]
→
[image]

If you want to insert some separator where you chopped out, you can achieve that with `-splice`.

`convert in.png -chop x92+0+50 -background black -splice x2+0+50 out-chopped-spliced-separator.png`

- `-chop` already explained above
- as the next processing step we change `-background` to `black` which applies to all later command in the queue.
- `-splice x2+0+50` From the default reference point top-left at X 0px and Y 50px splice in a row of full width (nothin specified in front of the `x`) and of 2px height. Because we have set the background color black in the previous step that 2px row is filled black.

## Batch processing

```
mogrify -path ../batch-done -chop x92+0+50 -background black -splice x2+0+50 *
```

- `mogrify` keeps the same filename of each input file for the corresponding output file. Normally it overwrites in place. But we use:
- `-path` to write the out files to target directory `../batch-done`
- `*` to consider all files of your current directory via shell globbing as the input files of your batch.

### Sources

- v7 man page on [-chop](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop)
- v6 legacy manpage with sample images on [Chop, removing rows, columns and edges](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop)

Comment: FYI: There's also a StackExchange solution for this as a [Photoshop action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/156358/168945).